# Accelerator in WinAPI with 2 alphabetical keys

Tags: winapi, acceleratorkey

Is there a way to create an accelerator in WinAPI with two alphabetical keys? For example, Ctrl+A+S.
How a resource should look like in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32 accelerators of this form are not supported. If you wish to support such key presses, you need to implement the input handling manually.